# flutter_whatsapp depends on both integration_test ^1.0.2+3 and flutter_driver any from sdk, version solving failed

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies, flutter-test

Because every version of flutter_driver from sdk depends on vm_service 7.3.0 and integration_test 1.0.2+3 depends on vm_service >=4.2.0 <7.0.0, flutter_driver from sdk is incompatible with integration_test 1.0.2+3.
And because no versions of integration_test match >1.0.2+3 <2.0.0, flutter_driver from sdk is incompatible with integration_test ^1.0.2+3.
So, because flutter_whatsapp depends on both integration_test ^1.0.2+3 and flutter_driver any from sdk, version solving failed.
Running "flutter pub get" in flutter_whatsapp...
pub get failed (1; So, because flutter_whatsapp depends on both integration_test ^1.0.2+3 and flutter_driver any from sdk, version solving
failed.)

Am getting this  kinda error
Thanks in advance...

```
name: flutter_whatsapp
description: A new Flutter project.

# The following line prevents the package from being accidentally published to
# pub.dev using `pub publish`. This is preferred for private packages.
publish_to: 'none' # Remove this line if you wish to publish to pub.dev

# The following defines the version and build number for your application.
# A version number is three numbers separated by dots, like 1.2.43
# followed by an optional build number separated by a +.
# Both the version and the builder number may be overridden in flutter
# build by specifying --build-name and --build-number, respectively.
# In Android, build-name is used as versionName while build-number used as versionCode.
# Read more about Android versioning at https://developer.android.com/studio/publish/versioning
# In iOS, build-name is used as CFBundleShortVersionString while build-number used as CFBundleVersion.
# Read more about iOS versioning at
# https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/General/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Articles/CoreFoundationKeys.html
version: 1.0.0+1

environment:
  sdk: ">=2.7.0 <3.0.0"

dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter


  # The following adds the Cupertino Icons font to your application.
  # Use with the CupertinoIcons class for iOS style icons.
  cupertino_icons: ^1.0.3
  ext_storage: ^1.0.3
  intl: ^0.17.0
  http: ^0.13.4
  contacts_service: ^0.6.3
  cached_network_image: ^3.1.0
  camera: ^0.9.4+3
#  video_player: ^0.10.0+5
  path_provider: ^2.0.6
  fluro: ^2.0.3
  sliding_up_panel: ^2.0.0+1
  flutter_app_badger: ^1.3.0
  url_launcher: ^6.0.12
  shared_preferences: ^2.0.8
  android_intent: ^0.3.7+6
  permission_handler: ^8.2.5
  integration_test: ^1.0.2+3
  uuid: ^3.0.5

  # fast_qr_reader_view: ^0.1.5
  # fast_qr_reader_view:
  #   git:
  #     url: git://github.com/facundomedica/fast_qr_reader_view.git

dev_dependencies:
  flutter_driver:
    sdk: flutter
  flutter_test:
    sdk: flutter
    version: any
  # test: ^1.5.0

# For information on the generic Dart part of this file, see the
# following page: https://dart.dev/tools/pub/pubspec

# The following section is specific to Flutter.
flutter:

  # The following line ensures that the Material Icons font is
  # included with your application, so that you can use the icons in
  # the material Icons class.
  uses-material-design: true

  # To add assets to your application, add an assets section, like this:
  # assets:
  #   - images/a_dot_burr.jpeg
  #   - images/a_dot_ham.jpeg

  # An image asset can refer to one or more resolution-specific "variants", see
  # https://flutter.dev/assets-and-images/#resolution-aware.

  # For details regarding adding assets from package dependencies, see
  # https://flutter.dev/assets-and-images/#from-packages

  # To add custom fonts to your application, add a fonts section here,
  # in this "flutter" section. Each entry in this list should have a
  # "family" key with the font family name, and a "fonts" key with a
  # list giving the asset and other descriptors for the font. For
  # example:
  # fonts:
  #   - family: Schyler
  #     fonts:
  #       - asset: fonts/Schyler-Regular.ttf
  #       - asset: fonts/Schyler-Italic.ttf
  #         style: italic
  #   - family: Trajan Pro
  #     fonts:
  #       - asset: fonts/TrajanPro.ttf
  #       - asset: fonts/TrajanPro_Bold.ttf
  #         weight: 700
  #
  # For details regarding fonts from package dependencies,
  # see https://flutter.dev/custom-fonts/#from-packages
```